# Error building Sagemath8.1 on ubuntu 16.04 while installing

Tags: sagemath

I am having Ubuntu 16.04lts running on intel i3 5th generation.
I tried installing `sagemath` from source but keep receiving error msg:

[image: I have added a screenshot of the error msg.]

```
Error building Sage.

The following package(s) may have failed to build (not necessarily
during this run of 'make all'):

The build directory may contain configuration files and other potentially
helpful information. WARNING: if you now run 'make' again, the build
directory will, by default, be deleted. Set the environment variable
SAGE_KEEP_BUILT_SPKGS to 'yes' to prevent this.

Makefile:16: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1.
```

Additional info:

Drive's file system is `ntfs`.

Installed in this way:

```
$ export make -j4 
$ ./configure 
$ make
```

Comment: What is "Sage"?  For those of us who don't know what Sage is, we might not be able to give you the information you need.  Also, was there any output other than the error message you specified when you ran `make`?  If so, add that to the question as an edit, because that usually points at to why things failed.  The error messages alone are not useful enough to debug compile-time errors.

Comment: NTFS may be the problem - the build process likely expects the filesystem to respect Unix permissions (hence the message about "spkg-install should not be marked executable")

Comment: NTFS causes issues, but I would suggest that you follow that the other part of the error does, and email their sage-devel mailing list with the details they're asking about because that's what they *recommend* that you do.

Comment: It worked. When I changed the drive's file system  from ntfs to ext4 I cleared past the problem. but now I am getting                                                                                                                                                   To install small scripts to directly run Sage's versions of GAP,
the PARI/GP interpreter, Maxima, or Singular etc.(by typing e.g.
just 'gap' or 'gp') into a standard 'bin' directory, start Sage
by typing 'sage' (or './sage') and enter something like

    install_scripts('/usr/local/bin')

at the Sage command prompt ('sage:').